# How do I save cookies when I request a new page in one session?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have this code, and I login successfully:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
agent = Mechanize.new{|a| a.log = Logger.new(STDERR) }
agent.read_timeout = 60
def add_cookie(agent, uri, cookie)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  Mechanize::Cookie.parse(uri, cookie) do |cookie|
    agent.cookie_jar.add(uri, cookie)
  end
end
page = agent.get "http://www.webpage.com"
form = page.forms.first
form.correo_ingresar = "user"
form.password = "password"
page = agent.submit form
myarray = page.body.scan(/SetCookie\(\"(.+)\", \"(.+)\"\)/)
```

After I login I do not get redirected, so I looked at the webpage and Java is the one redirecting me, but if I use `page = agent.get("http://webpage.com")` all session cookies are deleted. And I have to login again , and it is a cycle because I don't get past that. I already tried several recommendations like `ignore_discard`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the right code to add the cookie but forgot to call it.
At the end try:

```
myarray.each{|line| add_cookie agent, 'http://www.sistemasaplicados.com.mx', "#{line[0]}=#{line[1]}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize automatically receives, stores, and sends cookies when using the same instance to get new pages.

1. Are you certain that the site is actually sending cookies?
2. Have you confirmed that Mechanize is really not sending the cookies? (Have you inspected the request headers it sends?)
3. You said "Java is [...] redirecting me"; did you really mean JavaScript?

Comment: @Phroz Thank you for the answer.

The site as you can see, is using a login form, which when I open and login if I close browser and open it again it would not be logged in, so I have to login again. I dont know if that answers if it has cookies or not. what I know is that after I submit the form in Mechanize.. and then use page again it asks me to login again in mechanize. As if I have not logged in before. In same Interactive Ruby Console.